# I'm following udacity's kotlin android lectures, error while refrencing ids, got to know about kotlin's synthetic support end. How to reference them?

Tags: android, kotlin, findviewbyid, synthetic

[layout with multiple textViews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCevy.png)

[mainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eAdV.png)

Comment: move your cursor to error view and press `Alt+Enter`

Comment: Try to learn android viewBinding or dataBinding. It will solve your problem. Follow this link  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: Thanks! though I referenced them directly in "listOf() by findViewById(------)" It worked but I will be learning viewBinding and dataBinding. Thanks again :)